# Añadir un directorio a la url de mi domino

Tags: reescritura-url

soy nuevo en javascript y necesito ayuda. Expongo mi problema:
Dentro de esta url:
https://ibaiarte.com/listing/intersport-loramendi/
y quiero añadir un botón para para acceder a esta otra url:
https://ibaiarte.com/es/listing/intersport-loramendi/

Como veis se trata de añadir el directorio /es/ tras el dominio. Pra ello he escrito este código:

```
document.getElementById("enlace").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   var urlActual = "2022.ibaiarte.com/es"+window.location.pathname;
   window.location.hostname = urlActual;
});
```

pero no me está funcionando y no me añade el directorio /es/ (el resto de la url sí que la está construyendo, pero sin el /es/

Comment: Ya probaste con `window.location.href = urlActual`?

Answer (score 0):

Sí, he probado con window.location.href, pero no funciona. De todas formas ya he encontrado la solución:

```
document.getElementById("enlace")
.addEventListener("click",function(event){
event.preventDefault();
let url2 = new URL('/es/'+window.location.pathname,'https://'+window.location.hostname);
window.location.href = url2;
});
```